# Recorrer un array devuelto por PHP vía AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo una consulta Ajax en la que recojo la id y la referencia de los aparatos registrados en el sistema pero no soy capaz de recorrer el *array* que me devuelve la función php:

MI PHP:

```
function getGadgetsReference(){

    $statement = "SELECT pr_gadgets.gadgetId, pr_gadgets.reference FROM pr_gadgets";

    $query = $this->db->query($statement);

    echo json_encode($query->result_array());
}
```

MI ajax:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){

    var base_url = $("base").attr("href");

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'index.php/welcome/getGadgetsReference',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {

        },
        success:function(e){

            console.log(e);
            $('#equipoAlarma').html(' ');

            $('#equipoAlarma').append("<option value='%'> Todos los equipos </option>");

            for(var i=0; i < e; i++)
            {
                console.log(e[i]['gadgetId']);
            }

        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

mi console.log

```
[
  {"gadgetId":"4","reference":"A001"},{"gadgetId":"7","reference":"A0010"},
  {"gadgetId":"5","reference":"A002"},{"gadgetId":"8","reference":"A003"},
  {"gadgetId":"9","reference":"A004"},{"gadgetId":"6","reference":"A006"},
  {"gadgetId":"2","reference":"A007"},{"gadgetId":"3","reference":"A008"},
  {"gadgetId":"11","reference":"A009"},{"gadgetId":"12","reference":"A010"},
  {"gadgetId":"13","reference":"A011"},{"gadgetId":"14","reference":"A012"},
  {"gadgetId":"15","reference":"A013"},{"gadgetId":"16","reference":"A014"},
  {"gadgetId":"10","reference":"A12"},{"gadgetId":"1","reference":"AAA05"},
  {"gadgetId":"17","reference":"AAA06"},{"gadgetId":"18","reference":"AAA07"}
]
```

¿Dónde me estoy equivocando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo es el `dataType: 'json'` no lo tienes especificado

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){

        var base_url = $("base").attr("href");

        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'index.php/welcome/getGadgetsReference',
            dataType: 'json'
            type: 'POST',
            data: {

            },
            success:function(e){

                console.log(e);
                $('#equipoAlarma').html(' ');

                $('#equipoAlarma').append("<option value='%'> Todos los equipos </option>");

                for(var i=0; i < e; i++)
                {
                    console.log(e[i]['gadgetId']);
                }

            },
            error:function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hazlo de la siguiente manera :

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
     console.log(value.reference);
     console.log(value.gadgetId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta más correcta es que me faltaba el

dataType: 'json' en la declaración del ajax.

De todas formas mil gracias sioesi por abrirme los ojos

Comment: Si te estaba regresando un string el server, lo que podías hacer era usar JSON.parse(respuesta) para poder hacer el loop.